# firebaseupdate remote config version to have the new data in my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem with remote config now i have start my app and my data was 117 and i add some more data it supposed to update remote config version to have the new data in my app
when i up data the version  i get the massage to update and all my data delated and re download  but dont get the new data only my old data
[enter image descript[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuPgW.png)ion here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3iHx.png)

i tried to change virgin number to many time but i don't have any result